# Blazor Server app call to a Web Api, both with windows authentication, fails with 401 error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor-server-side

Need to develop a Blazor UI that talks to a web api. I created the following in Visual Studio 2022, both in same solution:

*For the Web API:*

- Create New Project > ASP.NET Core Web API
- Framework: .Net 7.0
- Authentication Type: Windows
- Configure for HTTPS: checked
- Use controllers: checked

(all other check boxes left unchecked)

*For the Blazor Server App*

- Create New Project > Blazor Server App
- Framework: .Net 7.0
- Authentication Type: Windows
- Configure for HTTPS: checked

(all other check boxes left unchecked)

I then made changes in both apps:

In Web Api project, in WeatherForecastController.cs, added endpoint:

```
public async Task<int> GetA()
{
   return await Task<int>.Run(() => 1);
}
```

In Blazor Server App, in the out-of-the-box Counter page code I am making this call in the button click event:

```
try {int i = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("https://localhost:44370/weatherforecast/GetA");}
catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Using the IIS Express profile for both projects, I started a debug instance of the web api project, and then the Server App. *(Note: the 44370 port was the sslPort value from launchSettings.json of web api project.)*

On the UI Counter page, when I clicked on the button to make the endpoint call, the GetFromJsonAsnc call errored with

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (localhost:44370)'
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Did some research, and in Program.cs of the web api project, I added the cors lines:

Line string corsPolicy

Lines builder.Services.AddCors...., *(Note: the 44370 port was the sslPort value from launchSettings.json of Blzor Server app project.)*

Line App.UseCors

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

string corsPolicy = "corsPolicy";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: corsPolicy,
                      policy => {
                          policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44389")
                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors(corsPolicy);
app.Run();
```

Now I am getting the error at the GetFromJsonAsync

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).'
```

Can anyone help me get past this latest error? It can't/shouldn't be that difficult, so I suspect I am missing something very obvious. I believe the cors lines are needed, even though these apps are going to be run within our network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to enable Windows authentication for HttpClient requests.

Something like this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => {
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true,
    };
    return new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44370") };
});
```

And making the call, something like this:

```
@inject HttpClient client

// ...

try
{
    int i = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<int>("weatherforecast/GetA");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle exception
}
```

Comment: Varin thank you for your suggestion. I did need to add a scoped service.